# How to stop HTML table from resizing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a tic-tac-toe game.

A user may click a grid to place a cross. I'm having difficulty figuring out how to place an cross (X) without the **table automatically resizing**:

As seen in the codepen demo, whenever one clicks a "td" element, the table expands to fill the "X".

I've tried `table-layout: fixed` and `white-space: nowrap` to no avail. Can anyone enlighten me on this, or provide a working variant?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ppXgKZ

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap;"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    width: 20%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  td {
    width: 33.333%;
    border: 6px solid black;
  }
  td::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin-top: 100%;
  }
```

**JS** (jquery)

```
$("td").on("click", function() {
  $(this).text("X");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your code.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BJgjbm

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="white-space: nowrap;"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    width: 20%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  td {
    width: 33.333%;
    border: 6px solid black;
  }
  td::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin-top: 100%;
  }
  
.nopos{
  position:absolute;
}
```

**JS**

```
$("td").on("click", function() {
  $(this)
    .html("<div class='nopos'>XXX</div>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be a better and simple way:

```js
$("td").on("click", function() {
  $(this).text("X");
});
```

```css
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
 
  }
tr{
  overflow:hidden;
}
  td {
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    max-width: 33.333%;
    border: 6px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have just changed the CSS

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is in the CSS td::after.  When you place the X in the box it creates a new line that increases the box size when entered.  To get around this you can just add "float: left" to the td::after CSS rule.